# How to initialize a 2-D array inside a Constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying to initialize a 2D matrix inside my constructor which i will furthur change according to my requirement.

```
class Player{
string pName;
char playerBoard[ROW][COL];
public:
    Player(string name){
        this->pName=name;
        for(int i=0;i<ROW;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<COL;j++){
                this->playerBoard[i][j] = ".";
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Any alternate way to initialize this?

Comment: `this->playerBoard[i][j] = ".";` should be `this->playerBoard[i][j] = '.';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a string literal(const char*) to a char array element. Change the double quotes to single quotes to indicate that this is a char and not a string literal(null terminated C string represented by a const char*).

```
class Player{
string pName;
char playerBoard[ROW][COL];
public:
    Player(string name){
        this->pName=name;
        for(int i=0;i<ROW;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<COL;j++){
                this->playerBoard[i][j] = '.'; //<-chage this
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked , it was a silly mistake on my end.